# cakePHP File not found when using http://www.example.com/controller

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to install cakePHP in my localhost. I use linux mint, Apache, MySQL

In /etc/apache2, there are folders 'conf.d', 'mods-available', 'mods-enabled', 'ports.conf', 'sites-available', and 'sites-enabled'

Since my DocumentRoot is /var/www but, i want to keep cakePHP in /home/works/ .
So,

(1.) i create a file name 'cakephp' inside /etc/apache2/sites-enabled.

(2.) Then, write

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /home/works/cakephp/app/webroot
  ServerName local.ttt.cakephp
</VirtualHost>
```

(3.) After that I edit the file /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1   local.ttt.cakephp
```

(4.) Trying url: http://local.ttt.cakephp

The result: It's working and CSS is loaded, too

(5.) I trying to do a simple controller name 'Tests'.
Then, try url: http://local.ttt.cakephp/Tests

The result: It shows

```
Not Found
The requested URL /Tests was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu) Server at local.ttt.cakephp Port 80
```

My solving:
(1.) check file rewrite.load in apache2/mods-available
It has LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so and no comment #

(2.) Change 'AllowOverride None' to 'AllowOverride All' in file apache2/sites-available/default
It will be this

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
```

The result: It's not working, still show 'Not Found' page.

Some one know what my mistake?
Thank you so much.

Comment: you should use lowercase_underscore for controllers and actions in urls. but that should not matter for your problem. did you restart apache?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you change the directory path:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory /home/works/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

### 1.) Move your Directory tag inside of your VirtualHost tag:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /home/works/cakephp/app/webroot
    ServerName local.ttt.cakephp

    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

### 2.) Change your Directory tag's path to mach your DocumentRoot's path:

```
    <Directory /home/works/cakephp/app/webroot/>
```

### 3.) In the end you should have something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /home/works/cakephp/app/webroot
    ServerName local.ttt.cakephp

    <Directory /home/works/cakephp/app/webroot/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

### 4.)  This all assumes that mod_rewrite is enabled.

I'm pretty sure that Mint has the a2enmod command so you might want to use it:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

### 5.) Be sure to restart apache.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Hopefully that works for you.